# How to activate quota for users on folders?

Tags: windows-server-2003, quota

There is any way to limit usage on folders with quota on Windows 2003 Server?

I know it's possible for volumes, but it's possible for folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, quotas are per volume only.

**Edit:** actually, it seems that Server 2003 **R2** actually includes enhancements to quotas, including the ability to set quotas at the folder level in addition to old-style volume quotas. See if [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configuring-Volume-Folder-Quotas.html) meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move to Windows 2008 Server to get more granular control of your quotas out of the box.  Otherwise, you'll have to look into 3rd party quota solutions.